# static bool is always true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form application that looks like such.

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    private static bool _changed = false;

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(_changed)
         {
             //some code here
         }
    }

    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/MyPage.aspx");
    }

    protected void dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _changed = true;  
    }
}
```

So the gist of what I'm trying to do is that I have a form, which contains a drop down list and a save button. If the user makes a change to the drop down list, I set the private boolean `changed` to be true. By default, it is false.

For some reason that I do not understand, `changed` is true when it gets to the `btnSave_click` method even though it never visited the `dropdownlist_selectedIndexChanged` method, which is the only place in my code that sets `changed` to be true.

The markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="myDropDown" runat=server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
<asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>

<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Remember that a static variable will keep its value until the app pool recycles or the value is otherwise reset. Also keep in mind that unless you want a single user to change the value for ALL users, a static member is absolutely the wrong choice.

Comment: Static is shared for all users, if you have two people visiting the site at the same time, one of them could trigger the change which would affect them both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you really sure that you want to use a `static` field variable which is shared across **all requests**? So when UserA selects something in the DropDown, UserB will also have `_changed` = true.

You might want to use a `ViewState` or `Session` variable instead, e.g.:

```
private bool HasChanged
{
    get { object b = ViewState["HasChanged"] ?? false; return (bool)b; }
    set { ViewState["HasChanged"] = value; }
}
```

[**Nine Options for Managing Persistent User State in Your ASP.NET Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think the `SelectedIndexChanged` gets triggered by the `<select>` element getting populated with it's initial values. This means that while your form is initializing, before the user can even interact with it, your `dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged()` method is being invoked. You can verify this by using a debugger to see when this method is being executed.

Also, as others have mentioned, a `static` member is nto a good idea to store request variables; `ViewState` is better suited for this.

**UPDATE**

> I think the `SelectedIndexChanged` gets triggered by the `<select>` element getting populated with it's initial values.

This is not true.

I tested this out with a very simple web-app and the `SelectedIndexChanged` event does not get fired when initial values are being added to the `DropDownList` through the declarative file (MyPage.aspx).

I even tried to change the `SelectedIndex` programmatically in the code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Text", "Value"));
    myDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 2;
}
```

Still, even when doing this, the `myDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged` event does not get fired until changing the selected item through interacting with the webpage.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation supporting my claim of "I think the SelectedIndexChanged gets triggered by the <select> element getting populated with it's initial values." Does anybody know if this is true or not? I will experiment when I have some free time to confirm or disprove this...

Comment: I know it's not true in many cases, but I can't say with 100% certainty that it's *never* true given some sequence of events.